# How to read serialized object by spring @Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, serialization, redis

I have the serialized object string which is serialized by spring **@Cacheable** annotation.

I want to see the data inside it.

The serialized data that I got it from redis-cli is like below;

Iti is too long to share all data  here, I put the paste bin link; [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8kxJmy3Ksq/)

How can I convert it manualy human readable text or convert object independent Spring-data-redis.